# Can't find function Get_AacEncoder in open source project, even in system

Tags: c++, linux, github, aac

I'm compiling a opensource project, and compiled successfully.
https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac

But I have a problem when I using it, I found there's a function Get_AacEncoder() in aacEncOpen(), but I can't find where the Get_AacEncoder() declare, not in project, not in system, where is it?

Answer (score 0):

---

When you have built "fdk-aac" you are supposed to have {libfdk-aac.a, libfdk-aac.la, libfdk-aac.so, libfdk-aac.so.1, libfdk-aac.so.1.0.0}

```
$ objdump -Dslx libfdk-aac.so.1.0.0 | grep Get_AacEncoder
```

...  will show ~33 lines with of `Z14Get_AacEncoderi`

---

Comment: I want to know where is Get_AacEncoder() declare, I can't find it anywhere, why compile is ok?